# In Facebook chat, if someone is in my top list (I always see when he is online) does he see me too?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

If there are two people, X and Y who isn't in any specific list.

If X sees Y on the top list in chat, does Y necessarily see X too in the top list?